# Cannot boot Ubuntu 12.04 on Lenovo V570 fresh install

Tags: installation, boot

I just did a fresh install of Kubuntu 64 bit 12.04 (from the DVD) to a Lenovo V570 laptop.

- I did a dual boot install with Windows 7.  I used the boot layout leftover from Linux Mint 12 (which was working).
- The installation finished with what seemed to be a success.
- However, when rebooting, I get this error:
  GRUB: “invalid arch independent ELF magic” after install on SSD
- Then I did grub-install and update-grub (I didn't install grub-efi, so maybe this is the problem?)
- Then I got "unknown filesystem error" at the grub prompt.
- Desperately, I gave /boot the bootable flag.  Then on a reboot,...  I got some strange screen with the letters PXE.  It flashed momentarily, too fast to read, and then the computer jumped to a screen which asked me from which drive was the boot desired to be.

As of now, I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: Are you sure Ubuntu installed on the internal drive or it could be on the USB if you used a start-up disk to do this business and wrongly selected USB as the drive to be installed.The other thing possible is that you installed a wrong architecture different from your system like 64bit instead of 32.An Ubuntu 32bit works on both 32 and 64 but the later works only on 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 officially supported UEFI, so don't need to configure anything manually. But unfortunately, when I manually partitioned and install Ubuntu (with Windows 7 on Lenovo V570) it only started Windows7. Then I created a separate partition and select "Install Ubuntu alongside windows" rather than manually partitioned. Now at startup grub boot menu appears to select Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a couple of dual-boot V570s, which was simpler with the LTS release than with the earlier 12.04 beta, for which there was a need to blacklist acer-wmi.

1. Be sure to burn a complete set of recovery DVDs.
2. From the installation CD, partition as follows:

   - delete the empty and unnecessary LENOVO partition,
   - allocate about half the drive as the extended sda5 (ext4), setting it up as /, and
   - reserving about 1 GB more than your memory for a swap area. So for 6 GB memory, the swap will be 7 GB.
3. The installation will almost certainly screw up booting. Just hit Lenovo's one-step recovery. If you have data or programs in W7, this is where you use the recovery DVDs,-- otherwise you'll get a completely clean W7 installation. Before exiting W7,insert the Ubuntu CD and reboot into the "try without installing" mode.
4. In the file menu, click on the the Ubuntu (sda5) file system to make sure it's mounted. Then in terminal:

   ```
   sudo su
   mkdir /mnt/root
   mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/root
   grub-install--root-directory=/mnt/root /dev/sda
   umount /mnt/root
   reboot
   ```
5. The first reboot will give you the classic grub dual boot menu. Updating gives the nicer-looking current one.
6. I prefer Evolution to Thunderbird (especially since migration of emails with complex directories is a pain), but unfortunately it doesn't provide a messaging indicator. To fix this, gedit a file named evolution with the contents `evolution.desktop` into `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications`.
7. I also like the program Touchpad Indicator for giving several control options over the touchpad (such as disabling when a wireless mouse is installed). Again, no indicator.
   To fix this, go to System Settings > Startup Applications Preferences > Add, and

   ```
   Name: touchpad-indicator
   Command: /usr/bin/touchpad-indicator
   Comment: Starts Touchpad Indicator
   ```
8. I like to label the Windows drive as such. From the Software Centre, download GParted, highlight the Windows C: drive (sda2), then Partition > Label, enter Windows, then Apply.

The above installations work well and are very stable. A nice plus with the formal LTS release is that the Software Centre now includes Skype (which was bumpy in the beta).